# Replace CV axle on passenger side --Brakes not working now

Tags: brakes, hyundai, elantra

My husband replaced CV axle on passenger side and now after putting the tire back on the brakes go to the floor. They are fine until you put the tire on.

Comment: Had he disconnected a brake pipe while replacing the CV joint?

Comment: Are you saying that if you take the wheel off again that the brake pedal feels normal?

Comment: There could be a hundred reasons for this, all obvious. First, let's assume he did everything correct and just had to push the brake piston back into the caliper to get the pads off a severely lipped brake disc. Pump the brake pedal a few times to get feel back. If no joy then look for a pool of brake fluid on the ground, or jack the wheel and spin it listening for a horrible grinding noise because he forgot to put the pads back in the caliper, or a horrible clunking noise because he forgot to put the caliper back on the carrier. your problem is impossible to diagnose with this scant detail